# using map function on array - how to transform only one field (MEAN App)

Tags: angular

Below is a code snippet of the getClients() method of clientsService of an angular app.
This is about converting the _id field of the collections array of the data received from MongoDB to just id field - used in Angular Model.

Pls refer to the innermost return statement where I am transforming the clients array by changing the _id field of the response object with just id field - to match the Angular Client Model.
Is there a way to write this map statement without re-writing the fields which are not changing.

```
getClients() {
    this.http.get<{message: string, clients: any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/clients')
      .pipe(map((clientData) => {
        return clientData.clients.map(client => {
          return {                       
            // is there a better way of writing the below part. I just need to transform only one field.
            id: client._id,
            compName: client.compName,
            title: client.title,
            fName: client.fName,
            lName: client.lName,
            addr1: client.addr1,
            addr2: client.addr2,
            city: client.city,
            state: client.state,
            pincode: client.pincode
          };
        });
      }))
      .subscribe(mappedClients => {
        this.clients = mappedClients;
        this.clientsUpdated.next([...this.clients]);
        // emitting a copy of clients array and not the original array
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript spread operator, you can modify as below.

```
getClients() {
    this.http.get<{ message: string, clients: any }>('http://localhost:3000/api/clients')
      .pipe(map((clientData) => {
        return clientData.clients.map(client => {
          const object = { ...client };
          object.id = client._id;
          delete object._id;
          return object;
        });
      }))
      .subscribe(mappedClients => {
        this.clients = mappedClients;
        this.clientsUpdated.next([...this.clients]);
        // emitting a copy of clients array and not the original array
      });
  }
```